# the best overloaded method match for has some invalid arguments in Unit test case

Tags: c#

```
public void ApplicationNumberIsVaild_Test()
{
    MFA.Convana.BusinessLayer.ObjectModel.ApplicationNumber appno = new MFA.Convana.BusinessLayer.ObjectStore.ApplicationNumber();
    String Input;
    String Output;
    String TestCase;
    XMLHelper TestData = new XMLHelper();
    TestCase = TestData.GetTestDataString("IsValid");
    String[] arr = TestCase.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    if (arr.Length > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            Input = arr[i].Substring(0, arr[i].IndexOf(TestData.FieldDelimiter));
            Output = arr[i].Substring(arr[i].IndexOf(TestData.FieldDelimiter) + 3);
            Assert.AreEqual(appno.IsValid(Input), Convert.ToBoolean(Output));//Error in this line
        }
    }
```

Comment: Format your code. What does `appno.IsValid(Input)` return (bool)? Probably `appno.IsValid(...)` takes other parameter than `string`

Comment: Code-only questions are rarely good. What is the error? What have you tried to do to solve it? What do all the methods that you've not told us about accept and receive? Please reduce this to a [mcve]. (As an aside, now would be a good time to start following .NET naming conventions, and I'd recomment that you declare local variables in the narrowest possible scope, instead of declaring everything at the start of the method and *then* using the variables.)

Answer (score 1):

```
MFA.Convana.BusinessLayer.ObjectModel.ApplicationNumber appno 
    = new MFA.Convana.BusinessLayer.ObjectStore.ApplicationNumber();
String Input;
String Output;
String TestCase;
XMLHelper TestData = new XMLHelper();
TestCase = TestData.GetTestDataString("IsValid");
String[] arr = TestCase.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine },
        StringSplitOptions.None);
if (arr.Length > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        Input = arr[i].Substring(0, arr[i].IndexOf(TestData.FieldDelimiter));
        Output = arr[i].Substring(arr[i].IndexOf(TestData.FieldDelimiter) + 3);
        Assert.AreEqual(appno.IsValid(Input), Convert.ToBoolean(Output));//Error in this line

    }
}
```

There are three potential problems:

1. `appno.IsValid()` does not take a string for a parameter.
2. The string `Output` can not be converted to boolean.
3. The return value of `appno.IsValid()` can't convert to boolean.

Odds are appno.IsValid isn't returning a boolean. 1 is less likely to be the source of your error and 3 would most likely give you a different error message.